# How to get id from paths in Grapevine

Tags: c#, rest, grapevine

Its a simple question, but I haven't found any documentation. Grapevine 4.2.2

```
        //GET id
        [RestRoute(HttpMethod = HttpMethod.GET, PathInfo = "/api/[id]")]
        public IHttpContext GetDataId(IHttpContext context)
        {
            //how to get id?
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens as soon as you write a question, the answer will appear.

```
    //GET id
    [RestRoute(HttpMethod = HttpMethod.GET, PathInfo = "/api/[id]")]
    public IHttpContext GetDataId(IHttpContext context)
    {
        var id = context.Request.PathParameters["id"];
    }
```

https://gist.github.com/scottoffen/af9cac93dd1c26440690d9a768ca1117

Why Grapevine dont have a normal documentation?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This page has been here since before your question was asked. https://scottoffen.github.io/grapevine/docs/routes#accessing-route-parameter-values